# Elasticsearch: Unable to search with wordforms

Tags: elasticsearch, search, nosql

I am trying to setup Elasticsearch, created index, added some records but can not make it return results with word forms (for example: records with substring "dreams" when I search for "dream").

My records look like this (index "myindex/movies"):

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "What Dreams May Come",
    ... other fields
}
```

The configuration I tried to use:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "stem": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "standard",
                        "lowercase",
                        "stop",
                        "porter_stem"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "movies": {
            "dynamic": true,
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "stem"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And query look like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "Dream"
        }
    }
}
```

I can get result back using word "dreams" but not "dream".

Do I do something wrong?
Should I install porter_stem somehow first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't done anything wrong , just that you are searching in wrong field.
query_string , does the search on _all by default. And _all is having its own analyzer. 
So either you need to apply the same analyzer to _all or point your query to title field like below -

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "dream",
      "default_field": "title"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks like it helps.

Comment: I got more questions poking around elastic today :) If you have a chance, please, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096686/elasticsearch-full-text-search-made-easy