# ElasticSearch: Full-Text Search made easy

Tags: search, elasticsearch, full-text-search, sphinx

I am investigate possibility to switch to `ElasticSearch` from `SphinxSearch`.

What is good about `SphinxSearch` - full-text search just work out of the bot on pretty good level. Make it work on `ElasticSearch` appeared not as easy as I expected.

In my project I have search box with typeahead, means I stype `Clint E` and see dropdown with results including `Clint Eastwood` on the first place. Type `robert down` and see `Robert Downey Jr.` on the first place. All this I achieved with `SphinxSearch` out of the box just providing it my DB credentials and SQL query to pull the necessary fields.

On the other hand, with `ElasticSearch` I can't get satisfying results even after a day of reading about [Fuzzy Like This Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-flt-query.html), [matching](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html), [partial matching](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-matching.html) and other. A lot of information but it does not make task easier. I feel like I need to be PhD in search just to make it work at simplest level.

So far I ended up with such configuration

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "stem": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "standard",
                        "lowercase",
                        "stop",
                        "porter_stem"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "movies": {
            "dynamic": true,
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "stem"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Query look like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "clint eastw"
            "default_field": "title"
        }
    }
}
```

But quality of search in this case is not satisfying at all - back to my example, it can not find `Clint Eastwood` profile until I type his name completely.

Then I tried to use

```
{
    "query": {
        "fuzzy_like_this": {
            "fields": [
                "title"
            ],
            "like_text": "clint eastw",
            "max_query_terms": 25,
            "fuzziness": 0.5
        }
    }
}
```

It helps but not much, now I can find what I need with shorter request `clint eastwo` and after some manipulations with parameters with `clint eastw` but still not encouraging.

**So I wonder**, is there a simple recipe how to cook full-text search with `ElasticSearch` and get decent quality of results. I spend a day reading but didn't find the solution.

Couple of images to demonstrate what I am talking about:

Elastic, name almost complete but no expected result, note that there is no better match as well.

[image: Search 1]

One letter after, elastic found it!

[image: Search 2]

At the same moment Sphinx shining :)

[image: Search 3]

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch ships with auto [completion suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html). 
You need not put this into query functioanility , the way it works is on token level and not on partial token level. 
Go for completion suggester , it also have support for fuzzy logic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just tried, it works better, it does come up with result when I type `Clint E` for `Clint Eastwood` but still no joy, for example it can not find the guy when I type `Eastwood Clint`... and again, Sphinx does the job.

Comment: It looks like `ElasticSearch` requires too much effort to make it actually work. Probably it more capable but definitely not for quick start :(